# Appending data to a file dynamically

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have a file with a javascript code and an array below it containing lots of data. I have to add data to the array from a log file. The log file gets data continuously added to it and the new data has to be appended to the array without affecting the data previously held in the first file. Is there a way to do this using shell scripting?

Comment: `cat logfile >> arrayfile`?

Comment: show the file if you want help

Comment: It sounds like you need to implement the same functionality as `tail -f`.

Answer (score 0):

You can append to files using this:

```
echo "Hello world" >> file.txt
```

And i think you need this:

```
cat your_file1 >> your_file2
```

This will append your_file1 to your_file2.